# Quasar QTable lost state after returning from child component

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I have a QTable that renders link where user can click into detail page and use back button to return to this table later. If I move to page 2 and click on the link to view detail page, on return, the table state is lost and it's showing page 1 again.

I've tried using Keep-Alive in hope that component will not get destroyed but it didn't help.

How do I get around this problem?

[image: QTable with pagination]

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap the table within `keep-alive`, it will be kept alive as long as that page is alive. But, since you are navigating into another page, the table will be destroyed along with the page that contains it.

So, to achieve your aim, you must keep the whole page alive. You can do it like this:

```html
<template>
  <q-page>
    <!-- ... -->
    <q-table ... />
    <!-- ... -->
  </q-page>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'ThePageYouWantToKeepAlive',
  // ...
}
</script>
```

`keep-alive` has some props to manage inclusions/exclusions, you can use `include` prop to **only** include the page(s, *it accepts a comma-separated list, an array or RegExp*) that you want to keep alive. This way you would keep your performance loss to a minimum.

```html
<!-- /src/layouts/MainLayout.vue -->
<!-- ... -->
<q-page-container>
  <keep-alive include="ThePageYouWantToKeepAlive">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </keep-alive>
</q-page-container>
<!-- ... -->
```

The demonstration below would help to understand the situation better.

```js
// Source: https://codepen.io/yusufkandemir/pen/zYrZOKx?editors=1010
// Adopted from: https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/L613xva0/4/

const Foo = {
    name: 'foo',
  template: '<div><p v-for="n in numbers">{{ n }}</p></div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
        numbers: [Math.round(Math.random() * 10), Math.round(Math.random() * 10)]
    }
  }
}

const Bar = {
    name: 'bar',
    template: '<div><p v-for="n in numbers"><strong>{{ n }}</strong></p></div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
        numbers: [Math.round(Math.random() * 10), Math.round(Math.random() * 10)]
    }
  }
}

const Baz = {
    name: 'baz',
  components: {
    Foo
  },
    template: '<div><foo></div>'
}

const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar },
  { path: '/baz', component: Baz }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/3.2.0/vue-router.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <router-link to="/foo">
      <li>Go to Foo</li>
    </router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">
        <li>Go to Bar</li>
    </router-link>
    <router-link to="/baz">
      <li>Go to Baz</li>
    </router-link>
  </ul>

  <keep-alive include="foo">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </keep-alive>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the state of the table in the parameters of the route or vuex, localStorage.